# Distributing a PC game written with XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am interested in doing some development with XNA. One of the things that interested me most was being able to distribute on the XBox 360. However I haven't found anyone who uses it to distribute games for Windows. Is it possible? And what kinds of libraries do you need to ship with it (.NET etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good discussion of that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/10/31/9027445.aspx).